# how to collect json data in asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net, json, java-me

I have an asp.net web site say http://xyz.com with Default.aspx as landing page.

This url is accessed by a mobile application (j2me) which in turn sends JSON data as

```
JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();
jSONObject.put("firstName", "abc");
jSONObject.put("lastName","xyz");
```

Now i am facing the problem on how to collect this data on server side.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a class that will represent the entity send by mobile application:

```
public class MobileEntity
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize this entity in Page_Load method of your page like this (I'm assuming that mobile application is performing POST request):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    MobileEntity entity = null;
    if (Request.RequestType == "POST")
    {
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            entity = serializer.Deserialize<MobileEntity>(responseReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

That should do the trick (unless there are some other key assumptions that you have missed in your question)